# Why GIT says Fatal error no git repository file ,even though i added file before.............. (git add filename)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, git

```
touch filename
cat>filename.....(entered the content and saved it)
```

Then, I cant add file to git.
AS, `git add filename` is error (says no git repository)

Comment: If you're sure that you were able to do it before, it means that the '.git' hidden directory has been accidentally deleted or moved to another directory.

Answer (score 1):

It literally means that you are not inside a git repository, and git cannot figure out where to add/stage your files.
You need to first initialize an empty git repository with `git init` before you try to do anything.